# Android - How to blur the layout that is behind

Tags: android, layout, blur

I m trying to making a bottom slide view and when it pops up i want to get the entire layout from behind blurred.

I couldn't do it. I read that many people recommends the Library "Blurry" but it is not working.

```
Blurry.with(context).radius(20).sampling(2).onto((ViewGroup)linear);
```

linear is my LinearLayout that is behind my Constraint. I want to blur that linear

Comment: `but it is not working` how exactly?

Comment: Can you post the xml layout code you have used? It will help to determine why it is not working as you intend it to.